# Resource for Uma Samhita Tantram

Tags: tantra, devi, resource, samhita

I am looking for the Uma Samhita Tantram. It can be in Sanskrit, Hindi, English, or Telugu.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Uma-Samhita of the Shiv Purana it is in English by wisdom library.
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226545.html
Here is the Uma-Samhita as book 5 in Sanskrit of the same Shiv Purana.
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-sanskrit

Comment: thank you for the answer Haridasa . but i am looking for the uma samhita which is a samhita text or a tantra text i guess.

Comment: Hmm maybe try sacred text it may be a rarer scripture.